# How to remove Stretchy effect from Android Web View App?

Tags: javascript, java, android, jquery, android-studio

[image]

I m trying to make a web view app using android studio. Although I made a lot like these earlier, never faced this kind of stretching issue till the recent update.

Can anyone tell me if there is any Android Java fix or Jquery fix for this stretchy problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this snippet can work it out :

```
webView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

or xml :

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

Comment: or xml : android:overScrollMode="never"

Comment: `android:overScrollMode="never"` this one worked like a charm. Can you please add this to the answer. Thanks

Comment: Of course. You're welcome :) @HarishKolliparat

Comment: Can you please help me with this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71923437/how-to-make-javascript-getlocation-work-in-android-web-view